# android event after landscape calculation

Tags: java, android

I enabled onConfigChanges event and properly handling when device turns from portrait into lanscape. However, after onConfigChanges, when page is calculated again and finishes it, which event is fired? Thank you

Comment: I did on onResume and onRestart, and no luck, that is why am asking which one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says in the documentation "Some device configurations can change during runtime (such as screen orientation, keyboard availability, and language). When such a change occurs, Android restarts the running Activity (`onDestroy()` is called, **followed by `onCreate()`**). The restart behavior is designed to help your application adapt to new configurations by automatically reloading your application with alternative resources that match the new device configuration." [emphasis mine]

However, if you handle the changes yourself the only method which gets called is `onConfigurationChanged()`. Any changes you wish to make must be in this method, as none of the onX methods will be called. By handling the config changes yourself you've told it NOT to destroy and reload your app - thus, the page doesn't actually get calculated again. The only things which happen are those which you define in the `onConfigurationChanged()` method.

"Now, when one of these configurations change, MyActivity does not restart. Instead, the MyActivity receives a call to `onConfigurationChanged()`."

source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: that is true if you don't handle onConfigurationChanges. If it is handled, onCreate is not trigger anymore when device rotation

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand exactly what you meant. See my updated answer.